# Масштабирование таблицы с border-collapse: collapse

Tags: firefox, html, internet-explorer, css

У меня есть таблица c таким свойством:

```
.myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Изначально в IE (10) и FireFox выглядит нормально, но при масштабировании (zoom) линии между ячейками удваиваются (как будто вместо `1px solid` стоит `2px`).

Но вот [этот пример](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_table_border-collapse) у меня работает в IE хорошо. Но когда я вставляю этот код в свою страницу, то уже не работает (поведение такое же, как и у моей таблицы). В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Ваш DOCTYPE какой?

Comment: У меня

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Пробовал менять на 

    <!DOCTYPE html>

Вроде не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мой совет - не используйте таблицы. Ведь все можно сделать и без таблиц. В CSS можно сделать имитирование таблицы с помощью `<div>`:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"> текст </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col"> текст </div>
    </div>
</div>

.table{
display:table; 
}

.row{
display:table-row;   
}

.col{
display:table-cell;
}
```

Блоки `div` более гибкие, чем таблица.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, не будет смущать, что в парочке браузерах это не будет работать: [Web browser CSS support](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-css/)

Весьма полезная таблица. Например те же `table-cell` и `table-row` не будут работать в `IE6` и `IE7`. Хотя я бы на это не сильно обращал внимания, это уже `RIPPED browsers`.

Comment: IE6 уже как много лет ни кто не пользуется, в прочем так же как и IE7. Даже vk.com пишет что ваш браузер устарел. Хотя в IE7 у меня нормально работает, просто в css надо немного по другому.
Такой вопрос: а как проверить поддержку IE6, если в IE можно включить поддержку только 7 минимум.